# React with TypeScript: passing a number variable to a child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass down a variable which is a number to a component, but React seems to be turning it into a string.

This code:

```
interface Props {
  variable: number
  literal: number
}

const Parent = () => {
  const num = 2
  return <Child literal={1} variable={num}/>
}

const Child: React.SFC<Props> = (props) => {
  console.log(typeof props.variable)
  console.log(typeof props.literal)
  return <div/>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

will print:

```
string
number
```

---

How do I wrangle React into preserving the type of the variable when it passes it down?

Comment: a working snippet always helps :)

Comment: yea, what @JVLobo said... it should preserve type the way you have it

Comment: You are passing 2 numbers and it prints number/number. What is the issue ?

Comment: Hm.  It looks like this might be a TS issue, then.  Let me change the code.

Comment: Anybody know how to run the TS snippet?

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this

```
type Props = {
  literal: number
  variable: number
}

function Child(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  console.log(typeof props.literal)
  console.log(typeof props.variable)

  return <div />
}

function Parent(): JSX.Element {
  const num: number = 2

  return (
    <Child literal={1} variable={num}/>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

Check the console in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-surf-xgw6v)

Answer (score 1):

if any where you want integer instead string , you can use native javascript method for change Type of Variable , in your case you can get integer from string like this

```
  const num_integer =  parseInt(num);
```

and then you have integer

Comment: That will convert between types, yes, but I want the type to not be changed initially.